# Flutter Web App: Twitter feed like layout

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm new to flutter and I am working on a web app (*not* a phone app). I'm trying to create a layout similar to Twitter on the computer (not phone). It is even similar to stackoverflow itself. You have three columns:

Column 1: On the left with some basic menu items

Column 2: center and wider with a scrolling feed

Column 3: On the right with features/other helpful items in boxes.

With flutter, I have seen layouts that use the side menu but they are all the way on the left. They don't stick to the middle column.

I've attached an image of the general skeleton. I would love for any kind of help as to where I even begin. I've looked at SafeArea, Container etc. But since this is the base layout, I'm not sure what is the best practice for this and I want it to be a good start. Even if I can be pointed in the right direction, like start with this widget etc. I would appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will encourage to calculate the width and based on it change the viewport [like I used to](https://github.com/yeasin50/lisa_fischer/blob/master/lib/configs/config.responsive.dart)

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange, // for  screen background
      body: Center(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            final maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;

            return SizedBox(
              width: maxWidth * .8, //max viewPort
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: maxWidth * .2, //left part
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment:
                          CrossAxisAlignment.start, // for alignment
                      children: [
                        ...List.generate(
                          8,
                          (index) => SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                            child: Text("menu item $index "),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        child: CustomScrollView(
                          slivers: [
                            SliverList(
                              // prefer builder
                              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                                [
                                  ...List.generate(
                                    44,
                                    (index) => SizedBox(
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: Text("Body Element $index "),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: maxWidth * .2, //right part features
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ...List.generate(
                          4,
                          (index) => SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                            child: Text("features item $index "),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: So basically you are using a SizedBox to allocate the "drawable area" with a LayoutBuilder which gives the size of the window? So if I change the size of the window, I should be able to change the layout?

Comment: And also what do you mean by the comment "prefer builder in the scrolling widget?

Comment: yes, using `SizedBox`  to allocate the "drawable area" and prefer [SliverChildBuilderDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverChildBuilderDelegate-class.html)

Comment: Great thanks! Tried your build method and it seems to give me the layout to start with. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey, I do get an exception when I use the scroll view - Another exception was thrown: The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition
Any idea about this?

Comment: Are there nested scrollable widget?  or using same controller on multiple widget can you share that link

Comment: Could it be because I'm using listview on the left column?

Comment: I had to add `controller: ScrollController(),` in the ListView and the CustomScrollView for it to work.

Comment: Declarer and pass two controllers on `CustomScrollView` and `ListView`, it will solve the issue.

Comment: what happend when user paste url by url . imagine there is sidenav menu

Comment: @Sras if user pastes something it will be considered as string, you can convert it to url, I need test snippet to test, then I might be able to say more.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, I try to archeive by using auto_router package, nested navigation to create layout template (admin_layout, home_layout).